# Android display multiple lists values

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am doing android application. In That I want to display a List of podcast urls like shown in the Image. In this I also share this url into FB, twitter and etc and also the user clicks the arrow symbol I want to forward to that podcast url.

I am having those values in separate arraylist (i.e. "4353,3424" as a arraylist and "567567, 234234" as a another arraylist likewise). So how can I display these values like shown in the attached image. Can anyone help me how to proceed to display like this?

[image: Grid view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you had a look at some of the tutorials on how to implement your own custom `ListView`.

An example can be found here: http://www.thepcwizard.in/2012/09/android-creating-custom-listview-for.html

Also I'd recommend you create a custom class for holding the different informations in every row of the `ListView`. When doing it like this you can have one single `List<MyCustomObject>` holding all informations and then when a row is clicked, you simple get the item from the `List<MyCustomObject>` and get the specific property of the custom object and act accordingly.

EDIT: Small example of how to add onClickListener to a sub-view of the row:

Inside the `getView` method of the custom `Adapter` you can use `setOnClickListener` to the views, you'd like to respond to clicks. For instance:

`myImageView.setOnClickListener(this);`

Then let your custom `Adapter` implement the `interface` `OnClickListener` and act accordingly to the clicks.

Another way would also be to add a `Share Intent` to the different images, like in this example:

http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/sharing-content-in-android-using-action_send-intent

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked that example. It shows only the item click listener. But I want to listen if the user clicks the FB, Twitter and etc(like shown in the image above). So is it possible to set listener for "f" image, "t" image and etc...

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a custom `ArrayAdapter` to populate a `ListView` from this objects the way you want.

The advantage of this technic is that you gain a Views recycle mechanism that will recycle the `Views` inside you `ListView` in order to spend less memory.

**In Short** you would have to:

**1.** Create  an object that represents your data for a single row.

**2.** Create an `ArrayList` of those objects.

**3.** Create a layout that contains a ListView or add a ListView to you main layout using code.

**4.** Create a layout of a single row.

**5.** Create a `ViewHolder` that will represent the visual aspect of you data row from the stand point of `Views`.

**6.** Create a custom `ArrayAdapter` that will populate the rows according to you needs.

**7.** Finally assign this `ArrayAdapter` to your `ListView` in `onCreate`.

You can get an Idea of how to implement this by reading this blog post I wrote:

[Create a Custom ArrayAdapter](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=495)